# How can I expand my query so that I merge rows together with the same id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[ER-diagram:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Avx.png)

I am making a questionnaire application which asks the following:

- Enter month
- Type of inquiry (Phone, personal..)
- Duration of the call
- who is the supervisor
- Study status
- Which institution *
- Study programme
- Topic/category *

Where I need the answers marked with an asterisk from the database to insert into:
[Datadesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8qID.png)

The table that I'm using is QuestionAnswer:

|  | QuestionAnswerId | QuestionId | AnswerOptionId | FormularId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 109 | 2 | 1 | 27 |
| 2 | 110 | 3 | 4 | 27 |
| 3 | 111 | 2 | 1 | 27 |
| 4 | 112 | 3 | 4 | 27 |
| 5 | 113 | 2 | 1 | 27 |
| 6 | 114 | 3 | 4 | 27 |
| 7 | 115 | 2 | 1 | 27 |
| 8 | 123 | 3 | 4 | 29 |
| 9 | 124 | 2 | 1 | 29 |
| 10 | 125 | 3 | 4 | 29 |
| 11 | 126 | 2 | 1 | 29 |
| 12 | 127 | 3 | 4 | 29 |
| 13 | 128 | 2 | 1 | 29 |
| 14 | 129 | 3 | 4 | 29 |
| 15 | 130 | 2 | 1 | 30 |
| 16 | 131 | 3 | 4 | 30 |

... continues

I have created a query that gives me only the AnswerOptionId's and QuestionId's I need
QuestionId = 6 (= departments), QuestionId = 8 (=topic) And AnswerOptionId = 13-17 (is the selected topic) and the AnswerOptionId = 69-89 (is the selected topic)

```
SELECT *
FROM QuestionAnswer
WHERE QuestionId = 6 AND 
AnswerOptionId BETWEEN 13 AND 17 
OR 
QuestionId = 8 AND 
AnswerOptionId BETWEEN 69 AND 89
ORDER BY FormularId
```

Where the result is:

|  | QuestionAnswerId | QuestionId | AnswerOptionId | FormularId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 290 | 6 | 15 | 52 |
| 2 | 292 | 8 | 78 | 52 |
| 3 | 347 | 6 | 15 | 61 |
| 4 | 349 | 8 | 80 | 61 |
| 5 | 354 | 6 | 15 | 62 |
| 6 | 356 | 8 | 87 | 62 |

... continues

And I want it to be like:

|  | QuestionId | AnswerOptionId | QuestionId | AnswerOptionId | FormularId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 15 | 8 | 78 | 52 |
| 2 | 6 | 15 | 8 | 80 | 61 |
| 3 | 6 | 15 | 8 | 87 | 62 |

... continues

Comment: What does JQuery have to do with what you are asking here?

Comment: You need to pivot your data.

Comment: @Larnu hahaha absolutely nothing. It was a mistake, sorry

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest querying for each question separately and then joining the results on the shared FormularId.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    Q1.QuestionId, Q1.AnswerOptionId,
    Q2.QuestionId, Q2.AnswerOptionId,
    COALESCE(Q1.FormularId, Q2.FormularId) AS FormularId
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM QuestionAnswer
    WHERE QuestionId = 6 AND 
    AnswerOptionId BETWEEN 13 AND 17 
) Q1
FULL OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM QuestionAnswer
    WHERE QuestionId = 8 AND 
    AnswerOptionId BETWEEN 69 AND 89
) Q2
    ON Q2.FormularId = Q1.FormularId
ORDER BY FormularId
```

Result:

| QuestionId | AnswerOptionId | QuestionId | AnswerOptionId | FormularId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 15 | 8 | 78 | 52 |
| 6 | 15 | 8 | 80 | 61 |
| 6 | 15 | 8 | 87 | 62 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/22FbKLYZ).

If, for a given FormularId, only one of the questions satisfies your criteria, the results will show nulls for the other question. If you only want to include cases where both questions satisfy your criteria, you can change the `FULL OUTER JOIN` to a regular (inner) `JOIN`.